# Another DateTime.ParseExact question

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

I have the following code.

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;

   class testCompile
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CultureInfo provider = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
            string format = "mm/d/yyyy";
            string strInput = "11/5/2010";
            string strOutput = DateTime.ParseExact(strInput, format, provider).ToString();
            Console.WriteLine("string Looks Like : {0}", strOutput);
        }
    }
```

1) If I try to set the format to "mm/dd/yyyy", the above code throws an error at runtime.

2) I am getting an output of 1/5/2010 12:11:00 AM for the above code.

Where exactly is the 12:00:00 AM coming from?

How did Guy Fawkes Day change to 5th of Jan?

Could someone please explain what is going on?

Comment: Make sure to properly setup Try/Catch blocks if you are going to use ParseExact. Alternatively you can use TryParse/TryParseExact instead.

Comment: Thanks for everyone's contributions. I have changed my code to make it look like this.
**        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CultureInfo provider = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
            string format = "M/d/yyyy";
            string strInput = "11/15/2010";
            string strOutput = DateTime.ParseExact(strInput, format, provider).ToShortDateString();
            Console.WriteLine("string Looks Like : {0}", strOutput);
        }

Comment: @Crag,
Thanks for your comment. I have that in my original code. This is just a sample I created for the purpose of illustrating my problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) Since you didn't specify a time, it uses the default, 12:00:00 AM.

2) You need to use "MM" to specify the month in your format string, rather than "mm" (minutes). See [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx) for all the details you can handle.

Comment: string format = "M/d/yyyy"; is going to work for all situations.

Answer (score 4):

`mm` means minutes;  `MM` means months.

Answer (score 3):

The month should be capital `M` or `MM`.

See [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) for the complete reference.